# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Boolean IsAssignableFrom

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have an extension method IsAssignableFrom

```
public static bool IsTypeOf<T>(this Type type)
        {
            return typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(type);
        }
```

Which is called by:

```
var Type = typeof(BadgeNumVotesOnItem);    
var UnlockableBadges = DB.Badges.Where(t => t.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(Type));
```

However when I use it, it is throwing this exception:

```
{System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsAssignableFrom(System.Type)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at MVCDaemon.Helpers.AwardBadgesProcessor.AwardBadgesForEventViewedSituation() in c:\Users\William-Business\Desktop\TWB\Entrepreneurial dev\Hehe\Hehe.Daemon\Processors\hehehe.cs:line 27
   at MVCDaemon.Controllers.AwardBadgesController.FromUnprocessedEvents() in c:\Users\William-Business\Desktop\TWB\Entrepreneurial dev\Hehe\Hehe.Daemon\Controllers\hehehe.cs:line 29}
```

Comment: SQL has no concept of .Net types and methods. When EF is trying to convert your predicate to SQL, it doesn't know what to do. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I only want items of a subtype of a class

Comment: Are all subclass defined in your context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
var UnlockableBadges = DB.Badges.OfType<BadgeNumVotesOnItem>();
```

Assuming that 1) BadgeNumVotesOnItem is a sub-class of Badges and both are defined in your Entity Framework mapping (or in a TPT/TPH way on your database).

Otherwise it's not possible as the SQL doesn't have knowledge of your .Net classes that aren't mapped to a table.

**Edit:* You can't use it just because it inherits your model. Because you are mixing objects that have a meaningful relation to something in the database (what EF understands and can use to talk to the database) and something that exists solely in your application. You can't mix and match. Before materializing a LINQ query with EF, everything has to be done in the mindset of the Models you have defined in your context.

Let's take your query:

```
DB.Badges.Where(t => t.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(Type));
```

`DB.Badges` represents a table in your persistence layer and Entity Framework knows how to talks to it. The `Where` construct will be analyzed by Entity Framework to be translated to something your persistence layer can understand. The `Badges` set will be able to materialize (ie: translate a record into a meaningful class) the class `Badge` just fine, but the database doesn't talk `BadgeNumVotesOnItem` and therefor, Entity Framework can't do much with it.

Think of it this way: if you connect directly to your database, can you query for `BadgeNumVotesOnItem` ?

Comment: When you say its defined in my Entity framework mapping, what exactly do you mean? I have a set Badges in my context. And then the BadgeNumVotesOnItem inherits from Badges, but I havent declared that inheritence in the context or anything, it just inherits from the class is that ok?

Comment: See my edit for expanded comment. I think what you want to do can be done, but you're thinking too much in .NET Objects and not enough in Database (conceptually) to represent your query in a meaningful way, in code.

Comment: Thank you that's a big help! What do you recommend I do, Shall I just put a collection in the context for each subclass collection?

Comment: Yes, like the second snippet of caesay's answer. Beware that after `AsEnumerable`, everything in your database will be brought down in your application for the Where() filter. This is usually fine for small dataset, but terribly inefficient for large tables. If there is a way to pre-filter, I'd suggest that.

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to mention something, It's a sticky situation becuase it goes. Badges -> BadgeNumVotesOnItem -> BageNumberVotesOnItem5. So the discriminator is "BadgeNumberVotesOnItem5" but I need to test the type on the class in the middle

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var Type = typeof(BadgeNumVotesOnItem); 
var UnlockableBadges = DB.Badges.OfType<BadgeNumVotesOnItem>();
```

If your context doesnt have the class defined or anything then you can do this:

```
var Type = typeof(BadgeNumVotesOnItem);    
var UnlockableBadges = DB.Badges.AsEnumerable().Where(t => t.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(Type));
```

Which will then construct an SQL query that will return all badges, and then applying the Where expression. instead of trying to translate where expression into a SQL query to be done by whatever SQL engine you are using.

Comment: That is correct (if `BadgeNumVotesOnItem` is not defined in the context). But you should use `AsEnumerable()` to let Entity Framework materialize the query and not have to create an array unnecessarily, given the fact that you're then querying it.

Comment: How do you define it in the context? It's just inheriting at the moment . Only Badges is defined in Context